# loop through array text responses

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, arrays

I am trying to display a different output when a button is selected on my website.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="question">
  <p>How many sides does a hexagon have?</p>
  <button class="right-answer" onclick="showResult(this)">6</button>
  <button class="wrong-answer" onclick="showResult(this)">10</button>
</div>

<div>
  <p id="answer"></p>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
 var _i = 0;
 var _wrongs = [
   'Incorrect!',
   'Wrong!',
   'False!',
   'Mistake!',
   'Error!',
   'Retry!'
 ];

 function showResult(b) {
   var res = document.getElementById('answer');
   if (b.classList.contains('right-answer')) {
     res.innerHTML = 'Correct'
   } else {
     res.innerHTML = _wrongs[_i];
     _i = _i > 1 ? 0 : _i + 1;
  }
 }
```

When the incorrect button is selected, a value found in the `_wrongs` array should be displayed each time, and the output should not repeat itself.

This works to an extent, however...when selecting the incorrect answer numerous times, it seems to only output a maximum of 3 different responses, and will then start back up again.

How can I make it so that it will run the entire length of the array?

Comment: Basically this is what you're after, right? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19351759/javascript-random-number-out-of-5-no-repeat-until-all-have-been-used

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had a mistake in your ternary line.  Replace `_i > 1` with `_i >= _wrongs.length-1`

```
_i = _i >= _wrongs.length-1 ? 0 : _i + 1;
```

Here's an [updated codepen](http://codepen.io/sfletche/pen/aOYorE?editors=101) that works as you intended.

And just in case your curious...The [modulo operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators), `%`, which calculates the remainder of the division equation, would work nicely here too.

```
_i++;
_i = _i % _wrongs.length;
```

See [working example here](http://codepen.io/sfletche/pen/BNrBXa).

Comment: Hey @user1752759 - you were right.  I updated my response and the codepen example so you can see a working example.

Answer (score 1):

change this line:

```
_i = _i > 1 ? 0 : _i + 1;
```

to this

```
 _i = _i >= _wrongs.length  ? 0 : _i + 1;
```

Comment: After going through the entire list of incorrect responses, an 'undefined' output is displayed.  Your assistance in solving this would be very much appreciated.